# Recursive 'compose' in common lisp (translating from scheme)

Tags: common-lisp

I'm studying Common Lisp. Don't know Scheme yet.

I have no problem with following `compose` in Common Lisp

```lisp
(defun compose (&rest fns)  
  (destructuring-bind (fn1 . rest) (reverse fns)
    #'(lambda (&rest args)                       
       (reduce #'(lambda (v f) (funcall f v))    
               rest                              
               :initial-value (apply fn1 args)))))
```

(it's interesting the deep similarity between compose & reduce :) )

Then, reading around, I found an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)#First-class_composition) of `compose` in Scheme, but done recursively, like so:

```lisp
(define (compose . fs)
  (if (null? fs) (lambda (x) x)
      (lambda (x) ((car fs) ((apply compose (cdr fs)) x)))))
```

My attempt to translate the above to Common Lisp (rather in the dark here):

```lisp
(defun compose-r (&rest fs)
  (if (null fs)
      #'(lambda (x) x)                   ; base case
      #'(lambda (x) (funcall (car fs)    ; first given fn, applied to...
                     (compose-r (cdr fs) x)))))
```

Interestingly the above produces:

```
COMPOSE-R
[179]> (mapcar (compose-r #'list #'abs #'round #'sqrt) '(4 9 16 25 130))
((#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (X) (FUNCALL (CAR FS) (COMPOSE-R (CDR FS) X))>)
 (#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (X) (FUNCALL (CAR FS) (COMPOSE-R (CDR FS) X))>)
 (#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (X) (FUNCALL (CAR FS) (COMPOSE-R (CDR FS) X))>)
 (#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (X) (FUNCALL (CAR FS) (COMPOSE-R (CDR FS) X))>)
 (#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (X) (FUNCALL (CAR FS) (COMPOSE-R (CDR FS) X))>))
[180]>
```

So something's working but I missed a function call.

It would be great perhaps if someone could use this example to point out some key differences between Common Lisp and Scheme and to outline the key things one must know in translating.

I already noticed that in scheme it seems possible to evaluate an expression in position zero of an expression, whereas Common Lisp complains that "should be a lambda expression".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(define (compose . fs)
  (if (null? fs)
      (lambda (x) x)
      (lambda (x)
        ((car fs)
         ((apply compose (cdr fs)) x)))))
```

is

```
(defun compose (&rest fs)
  (if (null fs)
      (lambda (x) x)
      (lambda (x)
        (funcall (car fs)
                 (funcall (apply #'compose (cdr fs)) x)))))
```

Then:

```
CL-USER 53 > (mapcar (compose #'list #'abs #'round #'sqrt) '(4 9 16 25 130))
((2) (3) (4) (5) (11))
```

The main differences in Common Lisp:

- call function objects with `FUNCALL`
- retrieve a function object with `#'some-fun` or `(function some-fun)`

Comment: Aha - it was the sharp quote on the recursive call to `compose` that got me. Didn't think of that. Question: we don't sharp quote when a function comes immediately after an opening parens,... but why must we when a function is in another position? What is it in CL that creates that rule? Wondering what it is I don't understand properly so as to have made that error. (or is there not much mystery.. and it's just habit that's needed to do this...). thanks.

Comment: @mwal: If you have a function name and you want to pass a function object to somewhere (store it in a variable, pass it to a function), you need to use FUNCTION to retrieve its value. Scheme has only variables. Common Lisp has different namespaces for variables and functions. A single identifier can name two different things: a value and a function.

Comment: Yup, thanks - sorry, I meant I tried a few variants in addition to what I posted and what I _didn't think of trying_ was the sharp quote.

Comment: Is it correct to add: "with the single exception that when a function name appears as the first element of an expression/form(?), a call to FUNCTION is implicit"?